# javascript search for string in excel

Tags: javascript, excel, activex

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdata(x)
{
    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var excel_file=excel.workbooks.open("c:/users/B1ECDJAF/test1.xlsx");
    var excel_Sheet = excel_file.worksheets("Sheet1");
    var b=excel_sheet.cells.find(x);
    var c=excel_sheet.cells(b,2).value;


    document.write("$"+c);
    return data;
    excel_file.Close();
    excel.Quit();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
getdata(ipt4-002);
</script>
</body>
```

The xcel file has 2 colums, the first column is the part number , 2nd column is price.  example

ipt2-005  $1.97
ipt3-005  $5.98
ipt4-001  $5.97
ipt4-002  $9.99

I want to match the part numbers and pull in the price into my webpage.  I have multiple items around 100 prices to pull and want to have the prices in a spreedsheet so they are easy to change without changing the html code every time I change a price.  I want to use the same script to look up all the prices using different "part numbers"

Any help would be appreciated.

I was able to look up the price by just quering the correct cell for the item, but I would rather do search and match the part number, that way it is one code for all my items and I dont have to change the code for every item.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: I will recommend you a change in your approach by Uploading the prices into the Web application where you have the HTML page that is running that JavaScript file.

You can do that using numbers of methods: Uploading manually, using odbc to open the xls file, or the Object method. But, into the web server.

Comment: I did type the first letter in caps but it was by mistake on this question, in my actual code it was in lower case.

Comment: You can study this yourself: Open your Excel, click "Developer tools", click "Visual Basic", open "Help" menu and click "Guide for Visual Basic", click "Excel Object Model Reference", find "Range Object" and study, how to create a `Range` and get its value.

Comment: Why do this in HTML/js when you could much more easily do it directly in Excel?  Is there some reason to do it in a browser?